# How to rethrow generic exception in Haskell

Tags: exception, haskell

Given

```
f :: Int -> IO (Either SomeException Int)

g = do
  results <- mapM f [1,2,3]
  let (errs, succs) = partitionEithers results
  if null errs then return succs
               else  -- rethrow arbitrary exception
                     throwIO (fromJust . fromException $ head errs)
```

I would have expected `g` to rethrow whatever exception it encounters, however compilation fails with ambigous type variable. Sprinkling randomly with existential quantified helpers doesn't help.

How can I rethrow an arbitrary exception I encounter without loosing genericity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `throwIO $ head errs`.

The error message is because `fromException` needs to go to a type known at compile time. You provide no context for it to figure out what type it is, so it complains that the type variable is ambiguous.

Fortunately, you don't *need* to know what type it is. `SomeException` is an instance of `Exception`, too.  It can be rethrown without ever knowing what type it contains. In fact, if you look at the definition of the `Exception` class, it's just `toException` and `fromException`, which are conversion functions that lean on `Typeable` to ensure that they don't break the type system. `SomeException`'s instance for `Exception` just has the most boring possible definitions for those.

Comment: True. However now I get the ambiguous error when catching the exception: `tryJust (Just . toException) a` complains `toException`'s `e` not being fixed.. but it should work for all `e`s, shouldn't it?

Comment: Oh, it is just fixing `e` to `SomeException`.. that was non-intuitive :)